# How set the time to zero in given format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss(Java)

Tags: java

I am given an input date string for ex:`2015-06-02 12:60:30` and the output should be `2015-06-02 00:00:00` i.e how to set the `HH:mm:ss` to `zero` in the given format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00` format instead of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

it will change the hours, minutes and seconds to zero instead of actual values

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
String dateValue = dateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(dateValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
```

Something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't require validation of the input format, you could use a regular expression:

```
input.replaceAll("\d\d:\d\d:\d\d", "00:00:00")
```

However, note that this conversion is not necessarily one which yields a valid time: midnight might not be valid, depending upon the date you are converting and its time zone, so this might not yield a valid time. (The start of daylight savings time in Asia/Gaza is the oft-cited example).

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,6); 
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,2);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0); 
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

Date d = cal.getTime();
```

And to format it you can use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formatted = sdFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply provide a format for the portion of the "date" you want to keep, for example...

```
String text = "2015-06-02 12:60:30";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(text);

SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(out.format(date));
```

Outputs...

```
2015-06-02 00:00:00
```

This is a little trick, which is actually described in the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-)

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. **The method may not use the entire text of the given string**.

*Emphasis added by me*

Comment: Glad it could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   String strDate = sm.format(myDate);
```